# How can I make the values ​of this dataframe add progressively. Ex. the second is equal to the first + second and so on, as continuous time

Tags: r, dataframe

Im writing my code like this:

```
HoraLLamadaSimulado2 <- function(n = 50)
{
  tiempodellamada <- 0
  x <- 1
  HORA <- 0
  vec1 <- data.frame()
  while (x < n)
  {
    tiempoentrellamada <- (runif(n, 1000, 1010))
    LLX <- tiempoentrellamada
    HORA <- as.POSIXct(LLX, origin = "2019-01-01", tz = "GMT")
    #HORA <- HORA + tiempoentrellamada
    vec1 <- data.frame(HORA)
    x <- x + 1
  }
  return(vec1)
}
HoraLLamadaSimulado2()
```

And this is what I get. That is the uniform distribution 50 times. I cant make the sum for making it continous time.

HORA

2019-01-01 00:16:46
2019-01-01 00:16:46
2019-01-01 00:16:43
2019-01-01 00:16:47
2019-01-01 00:16:47
2019-01-01 00:16:47
2019-01-01 00:16:47
2019-01-01 00:16:48
2019-01-01 00:16:48
2019-01-01 00:16:43

Comment: From the question title, I'd think `cumsum` would be a useful function, but from your code and short output, it's unclear what you need to happen. Perhaps you can explain what you ultimately need? For a great example, start with `set.seed(2)` (or something) and use an `n` of (say) 3, then show the output you expect.

Comment: What I need is to create a datetime dataframe following a uniform distribution which gives you the time between the next datetime. But in my dataframe it's just giving the time between and not the sum with the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the use of `cumsum`:

```r
set.seed(42)
as.POSIXct(cumsum(runif(10, 1000, 1010)), origin = "2019-01-01")
#  [1] "2018-12-31 16:16:49 PST" "2018-12-31 16:33:38 PST"
#  [3] "2018-12-31 16:50:21 PST" "2018-12-31 17:07:09 PST"
#  [5] "2018-12-31 17:23:56 PST" "2018-12-31 17:40:41 PST"
#  [7] "2018-12-31 17:57:28 PST" "2018-12-31 18:14:10 PST"
#  [9] "2018-12-31 18:30:56 PST" "2018-12-31 18:47:43 PST"
```